Re-Import Gmail Emails into Outlook
I keep my emails in Outlook PST files.  Almost all of these emails are from Gmail.  I am using POP3 / SMTP for all accounts.
Recently, some of my PST files got corrupted and I had to revert to older backup PST files.  However, when using these previous backup PST files, Outlook won't download the emails that were already downloaded in the corrupted PST files, even though the are still available in Gmail.
In Gmail, I have tried setting these messages as 'unread' and move them back to the Inbox.  This has no effect.
Even though these files are not in previous backup PST files, Yes, somehow between the interaction of Outlook and Gmail, Outlook determines these emails have already been downloaded and ignores them.
How can I get Outlook / Gmail to re-download these emails?
Any suggestions appreciated!!

Additional Notes:
I've read a few items about removing a 'POP3uidl.db' file, but I don't seem to have one of these.
I could consider an approach with IMAP based accounts, but that would alter my 'workflow' quite a bit, as my current 'workflow' works with just one main 'Inbox' for the 8 or so, email accounts I regularly use.
I have found one work-around, but it is a bit tedious (so still looking for better solutions):

In Outlook, create an IMAP based Account for each of the Gmail
accounts.
In Gmail, move the messages back into the Inbox
In Outlook, after syncing the IMAP Folders, go to the Inbox. The messages should be there.
Grab those messages and drag and drop them into the Outlook folder,
you prefer.

(From my comment on one of the answers):
I actually created a new, fresh, vanilla PST for a couple of the accounts. Then in Gmail, mark the messages as Unread and move them back to the Inbox. The result? Still not download, as if seems to know they were once already downloaded.
There is actually a Gmail API.  I imagine somewhat similar to the Google Drive API.  Perhaps a bit overkill, but maybe something can do there.

Why not create a new PST and a new backup?

Is there a specific reason for using PST files with Gmail, as that's a depreciated approach? If Gmail is added normally through Outlook, it will be configured with an OST, of which auto rebuilds itself from the server upon a send/receive. The primary difference between a PST an OST is the former can have data asynchronously than what the mail server has, whereas an OST's data is always in sync with the server and data cannot exist within an OST asynchronously from the mail server. OSTs are the default for Gmail and Outlook emails.

@ JW0914 - This could be part of an alternate work flow.  The primary reasons for using PST files, is that they contain many folders and emails organized in those folders that don't match Gmail (Gmail folders are a bit different).  Currently, there is only one of these PSTs also doing the POP / SMTP sync.  So, perhaps, that could be separated out into an OST.

@ JW0914 - Another reason for the PST approach, is that I prefer to have just one Inbox for multiple accounts.  Switching between different inboxes can get a bit disorienting.

As mentioned in the comment above, you can create a new PST file. Based on my experience, I would suggest that it would be easier not to use a backup or repair PST file.
For POP accounts, you can select the option in the Gmail settings: Settings>>Forwarding and POP/IMAP>>Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded)。
For IMAP accounts, emails are synchronized, you just need to add them correctly to Outlook to access all the previous emails. Of course, you also need to enable IMAP in Gmail.
Here's a thread with detailed steps you can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1180949/cannot-add-gmail-account-on-outlook

I actually created a new, fresh, vanilla PST for a couple of the accounts.  Then in Gmail, mark the messages as Unread and move them back to the Inbox.  The result?  Still not download, as if seems to know they were once already downloaded.

Actually, upon further evaluation, the new PST did indeed import the data- ALL the emails from the Gmail account, going back to 2018.  But initially, it was empty, then every 15 minutes would download about another 300 emails.  So it took a while.  In any case, this could be part of a viable approach.
